# Key binding to generate a sparse tree from the kill-ring

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, sparse-tree

I want to set a key binding that creates a sparse tree of all headlines containing the string currently on the kill-ring.

Currently, I mark the text I want and save it to the kill-ring, then call `org-sparse-tree` to create a sparse tree from a regular expression (`C-c / r`). When prompted for the regexp, I yank the text in the kill-ring.

I would like to do this without calling an interactive function. If I already have my regexp in the kill-ring, just pressing a key combination would save me much time.

I have tried to pass arguments to `org-sparse-tree`, but this function doesn’t seem to work this way (it is interactive).

Comment: You have to go a level down to find out what it is doing. If you look at the source code for `org-sparse-tree` (do `C-h f org-sparse-tree` and then click on the `org.el` link at the end of the top line), you will see that in the `r` case, it calls (interactively) the function `org-occur`. So do `C-h f org-occur` to find out how to use it and then write your own function that grabs the regexp out of the kill ring and then calls `org-occur` with that regexp as argument. And if you make it a [command]() then you can bind it to a key of your choice.

Comment: @NickD: Very helpful comment.

Comment: I forgot to add the link: [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html) - sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks NickD for pointing me in the right direction. I wrote the following function that does what I need:

```elisp
(defun kill-ring-sparse-tree ()  
  (interactive)  
  (let ((regexp (car kill-ring)))
    (org-occur regexp)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'kill-ring-sparse-tree)
```

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answer.